# Weight Loss after reaching a plateau

Tags: weight-loss, training, plateau

I am a 46 year old male (Height 170 cms and Weight 179.7 lbs) and I have just been diagnosed as Type 2 diabetic two months back and put on a mild oral medication by my doctor. I prefer exercising outdoors and my daily routine (6 days a week) includes 5 mins of stretching, 30 mins of brisk walk, 25 mins of bicycling, 10 mins of skipping and 10 mins of breathing exercises. However, despite of my following this routine for last few months I am unable to loose weight below my current weight. I have lost inches around the waist but I still need to loose some weight. I am a vegetarian and I follow a controlled diet with no sugars. Really would appreciate if someone can help me on this...Thanks..

Comment: Have you considered running or lifting weights?

Comment: Do you feel more toned or see other indications that you are losing weight?

Comment: Thanks and Appreciate the answers by Dave Liepmann, Kneel-Before-ZOD and JohnP

Answer (score 2):

"I have lost inches around the waist but I still need to loose some weight"

If you've lost inches, you've lost fat mass, what is good. If you've lost fat mass and haven’t lost weight than you've gained muscle mass, what is also good.

Why do you believe you need to loose 'weight'? is it something you convinced yourself of, or did your doctor tell you to? If you are to fat, than you are on the right track, you're exchanging fat for muscle and your waist measurements combined with your stable weight are evidence of that.

If your doctor tells you to lose weight and he/she knows you started doing almost a full hour of exercise on average per day, he/she should know that your total body weight at this moment isn't a reliable indicator of how your fat percentage is doing. If he/she doesn't realise that and tells you to loose 'weight' rather than 'fat mass', than its time you look around for an other doctor who understands you can get leaner and healthier from doing exercise while not loosing or even actually gaining weight.

A controlled diet without sugars is always good, even if you weren’t a diabetes. Being a vegetarian kinda complicates things there though. The best diet for loosing fat, especially as you have type 2 diabetes is a low-carb diet. How strict a vegetarian are you? If you do eat fish, you may want to consider going for a low-carb or even a keto diet. If you don't eat fish, keto might be impossible and low-carb difficult, but I'm not quite sure there.